# AudioQueueStart fails when iphone app running in background iOS4.0

Tags: iphone, background, ios4, audioqueueservices, multitasking

I'm having difficulties starting the AudioQueue when my app is in the background with iOS4.0
The code works fine when the app is active, but fails with -12985 code when running in the background.

```
        err = AudioQueueStart( queueObject, NULL );


        if( err )
        {
            NSLog(@"AudioQueueStart failed with %d", err);
                = NO;
AudioQueueStop(queueObject, YES);
            return;
        }
```

For the code above, err is set to -12985

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've since learned that re-using an audioqueue from the background works just fine.  You just can't start new.

Comment: how to re-use?? specifically?

Comment: what? how? say something more plz

Answer (score 3):

Making sure that my AudioSession was active fixed the problem:
Previously in code I had set the session to inactive between song changes before starting a new song:

AudioSessionSetActive(false);

Once I removed this AudioQueueStart works just fine from the background.

Answer (score 3):

From Apple Developer Forums:

> The solution is actually simple once you know it, and I really wonder
>   why so many question like your spread in many forums don't get answred

...

You to this ensuring your view becomes First Controller and then calling

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
```

n `viewDidLoad`. Once you do this, your Player will no longer return NO!!

Comment: yasirmturk, you are my hero! What a great answer. 1000 points. Thanks